# Soma de valor acumulado SQL

Tags: sql-server

Tenho um valor em estoque e preciso exibir a informação das movimentação do estoque baseado em nota fiscal.

**Tabela Movimentação**

```
Cod | Tipo | NumeroNota | Quantidade | DataEmissao | Material
 1  |  S   |    12312   |    1       |  2019-05-16 |     1
 2  |  S   |    12313   |    4       |  2019-05-17 |     1
 3  |  E   |    12316   |    10      |  2019-05-17 |     1
 4  |  S   |    12317   |    9       |  2019-05-18 |     1
 5  |  S   |    12323   |    6       |  2019-05-20 |     1
 6  |  S   |    12325   |    12      |  2019-05-20 |     1
 7  |  E   |    12333   |    3       |  2019-05-24 |     1
```

A coluna `Tipo` refere a entrada e saída, representadas pelas letras iniciais..

**Tabela Historico Estoque**

```
Cod | DataEstoque | Quantidade | Material
 1  |  2019-05-16 |     24     |    1         -> Antes da data tinha 25
 2  |  2019-05-17 |     30     |    1
 3  |  2019-05-18 |     21     |    1
 4  |  2019-05-19 |     21     |    1
 5  |  2019-05-20 |     3      |    1
...                                           -> repete a mesma quantidade para os dias sem movimentação
 9  |  2019-05-24 |     6      |    1
```

Tendo conhecimento da tabela acima, o que imagino é pegar o estoque na tabela `HistoricoEstoque` com base na data final (`HistoricoEstoque.DataEstoque = @DataFim`), assim tenho acesso a quantidade de estoque na data fim. Join com a tabela `Movimentacao` de forma a buscar a quantidade movimentada entre o intervalo `@DataInicio` e `@DataFim` fazendo uma regreção no estoque observando o Tipo da movimentação (Entrada (E) e Saída (S)).

Como a `quantidade` é a partir da `data fim` do estoque, resalto que para cada movimentação do `Tipo = E` deve se subtrair(-) e para saída(+). Isso é, pois esta fazendo ao contrário.

Quero saber, o estoque e a movimentação do material no intervalo de duas datas.

**Resultado esperado:** Filtro: *Data inicio* = 2019-05-17 e *data fim* = 2019-05-20

```
Material|DataEmissao|Quantidade|EstoqueAtual
    1  |2019-05-20 |   -12    |     3    -> tenha ser o estoque atual
    1  |2019-05-20 |   -6     |     15
    1  |2019-05-18 |   -9     |     21
    1  |2019-05-17 |   10     |     30
    1  |2019-05-17 |   -4     |     20
    1  |2019-05-16 |   -      |     24
```

O que é possível fazer? Existe outra sugestão?

Comment: Calma pessoas, estou alterando a pergunta. Os cara dão negativo sem ao menos informar o motivo, é complicado agradar a galera por aqui. @Sorack realmente falta detalhes, estou completando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode recuperar o resultado desejado com a seguinte `query`:

```
DECLARE @inicio   DATE;
DECLARE @fim      DATE;
DECLARE @material INTEGER;

SET @inicio = '2019-05-17';
SET @fim = '2019-05-20';
SET @material = 1;

WITH cumulativo AS (
  SELECT TOP(1) 0 AS cod,
                e.dataestoque AS dataemissao,
                e.quantidade
    FROM estoque e
   WHERE e.dataestoque < @inicio
     AND e.material = @material
   ORDER BY e.dataestoque DESC
  UNION
  SELECT m.cod,
         m.dataemissao,
         CASE m.tipo WHEN 'E' THEN m.quantidade ELSE m.quantidade * -1 END
    FROM movimentacao m
   WHERE m.dataemissao BETWEEN @inicio AND @fim
     AND m.material = @material
)
SELECT c.dataemissao,
       c.quantidade,
       SUM(c2.quantidade) AS total
  FROM cumulativo c
  INNER JOIN cumulativo c2 ON c.dataemissao >= c2.dataemissao
                          AND c.cod >= c2.cod
  GROUP BY c.dataemissao,
           c.cod,
           c.quantidade
  ORDER BY c.dataemissao,
           c.cod
```

---

> [`WITH`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> **APLICA-SE A:** `SQL Server` (a partir do 2008), `Banco de Dados SQL do Azure`, `SQL Data Warehouse do Azure` e `Parallel Data Warehouse`
>
> Especifica um conjunto de resultados nomeado temporário, conhecido como uma `CTE` (expressão de tabela comum). Ela é derivada de uma consulta simples e definida no escopo de execução de uma única instrução `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` ou `MERGE`. Esta cláusula também pode ser usada em uma instrução CREATE VIEW como parte da instrução `SELECT` que a define. Uma expressão de tabela comum pode incluir referências a si mesma. É o que chamamos de expressão de tabela comum recursiva.
>
> [**Sintaxe**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)
>
> ```
> [ WITH <common_table_expression> [ ,...n ] ]  
>
> <common_table_expression>::=  
> expression_name [ ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]  
> AS  
> ( CTE_query_definition )
> ```
>
> [**Argumentos**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)
>
> `expression_name`
>
> É um identificador válido para a expressão de tabela comum. `expression_name` deve ser diferente do nome de qualquer outra expressão de tabela comum definida na mesma cláusula `WITH <common_table_expression>`, mas `expression_name` pode ser o mesmo que o nome de uma tabela base ou exibição. Qualquer referência a `expression_name` na consulta usa a expressão de tabela comum, e não o objeto base.
>
> `column_name`
>
> Especifica um nome de coluna na expressão de tabela comum. Não são permitidos nomes duplicados em uma única definição de `CTE`. O número de nomes de coluna especificado deve corresponder ao número de colunas no conjunto de resultados da `CTE_query_definition`. A lista de nomes de colunas será opcional somente se forem fornecidos nomes distintos para todas as colunas resultantes na definição da consulta.
>
> `CTE_query_definition`
>
> Especifica uma instrução `SELECT` cujo conjunto de resultados popula a expressão de tabela comum. A instrução `SELECT` de `CTE_query_definition` deve atender aos mesmos requisitos da criação de uma exibição, com a exceção de que uma `CTE` não pode definir outra `CTE`. Para obter mais informações, consulte a seção Comentários e [`CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
>
> Se mais de uma `CTE_query_definition` for definida, as definições de consulta poderão ser unidas por um destes dois conjuntos de operadores: `UNION ALL`, `UNION`, `EXCEPT` ou `INTERSECT`.